# What makes a regular measure "regular"?

Tags: measure-theory

I get that definition, that $m$ is a regular measure if:  $$m(A) = \inf \left\{ m(U) \: | \: A \subset U, \text{ U - open} \right\} = \sup \left\{ m(K) \: | \: K \subset A, \text{ K - compact} \right\}$$

But what makes this definition a definition of a **regular** measure? What makes a regular measure "regular"?

Why are regular measures interesting for us?

Comment: The word 'regular' is used for a lot of different things in mathematics. I think of measure regularity as a continuity property, and that intuition comes from picturing $A$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and either approximating it 'from outside' with open sets, or approximating it by 'filling it up' with compact subsets.

Comment: Also, note that the properties 'open' and 'compact' depend on the topology of the space. Regularity is therefore a property about the interplay of the two structures (topological space and measure space).

Comment: Thank you, this really helps

Comment: @anon Here is my view:  A regular measure is determined by it's values on open sets, or by it's values on compact sets and these sets are nice to work with. This allows you to prove results for open/compact sets which are nice and then get consequences for all Borel sets.